# I want substring key use on condition base

Tags: xslt-1.0

1. I  have  two param  one is for  separator and second is for sub
   string if p then  substring-before otherwise substring-after.

my Input  XML .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<results>
    <result>
        <Store>0180|1</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>0180|2</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>0181</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>0183</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>abc</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>def</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>0181|2</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>0180|3</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>0181|1</Store>
    </result>

</results>
```

Xslt if fix=p then substring-before otherwise substring-after on key :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="name" select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:param name="fix"  select="'p'"/>
    <xsl:choose>        
        <xsl:when fix='p'>
 <xsl:key name="groups" match="/results/result" use="substring-before(Store,'|')" />

        </xsl:when>
<otherwise>
      <xsl:key name="groups" match="/results/result" use="substring-after(Store,'|')" />

</otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>       

        <
        <xsl:template match="/results">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$fix='p'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="result[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', substring-before(Store,'|'))[1])]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="result[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', substring-after(Store,'|'))[1])]"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="result">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$fix='p'">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', substring-before(Store,'|'))">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(Store,'|')">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(Store,'|')"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="'|'"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Store"/>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', substring-before(Store,'|'))">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(Store,'|')">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Store,'|')"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="'|'"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Store"/>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

An `xsl:key` definition must be at the top level of your stylesheet.
Conversely, `xsl:choose` cannot be at the top level.

Try this as your starting point;

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="key-direction" select="'before'"/>

<xsl:key name="key-before" match="result" use="substring-before(Store, '|')"/>
<xsl:key name="key-after" match="result" use="substring-after(Store, '|')"/>

<xsl:template match="/results">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$key-direction='before'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="result[generate-id()=generate-id(key('key-before', substring-before(Store,'|'))[1])]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="result[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-after', substring-after(Store,'|'))[1])]"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- more templates -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note also that:

```
substring-before('abc', '|')
```

returns an empty string. This means that:

```
<Store>0181</Store>
```

and

```
<Store>0181|1</Store>
```

are not going to be grouped together, unless you replace:

```
substring-before(Store, '|')
```

with:

```
substring-before(concat(Store, '|'), '|')
```